# .Net Core MVC - How to configure method that uses another Models data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.0

I am struggling in how to achieve the following. I have a basic CRUD application, where the user can book gym classes.

I have a Member model and controller (representing the individual members of the gym).

I then have a Classes model and controller (representing the classes the gym has available to book).

I have a BookClass method, which is visible when the user drills into the Details method of an individual method:

[image]

Now when the user clicks this, I want list of the Gyms Classes to appear. This will be my HttpGet method, once I get this working I'll create a POST method

This is my Classes Model:

```
    public class Classes
{


    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string  ClassName { get; set; }

    public int ClassSize { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfBookings { get; set; }   

    public List<Member>MemberClassBookings { get; set; }




}
```

Here is my BookClass method that I am trying to configure (this is in my Members controller)

```
        [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BookClass(int? memberid)
    {

        if (memberid == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var getClasses =  (from cn in _context.Classes
                                where cn.NumberOfBookings < cn.ClassSize
                                select cn);







        return View(getClasses);
    }
```

All my controllers pass the DBContext class via Dependency Injection:

```
        public MembersController(GymContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
```

So I can access things like _context.Classes to get the Classes data..

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Whats actually the question?

Comment: I am trying to get all of the Classes data and pass that into a View in my Members Controller (in the BookClass method)

So when the user clicks Book Class, the next View that loads contains all the records from the Classes database and the user can pick one

Comment: So what exactly is what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I am not sure how to pass the queried list of Classes available (my getClasses variable)  into the view. I don't believe passing the getClasses into the return View will work?

Comment: Why do you not think it will work? What model does the "BookClass" view use?

Comment: 2 ways of doing this, either create a ViewModel that has the data attached or pass the data in the viewbag.   `ViewBag.Classes = yourDbCall`, I recommend ViewModel... We need to see the top portions of your view(s) as well.  Looking at your history as well shows you more or less asked this question before.